# Set State cause use memo rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

Here is the code , no idea why Mem re-render after set state, as it is a memoized component, or if i wanna remember the component with set state, i should use useRef? that stupid??

```
const Demo = () => {
    console.log("render")

    const data = LoadSomeData();

    return (<>{data.id}</>)
}

const Mycomp = ({...props}) => {

    const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);

    const Mem = useMemo(() => <Demo />, [props.iwandToReloadData]);

    return (
        <>
        { showSearch ? 
            <button onClick={()=>setShowSearch(false)}>Back</button>
        :
        <>
            {Mem}
            <button onClick={()=>setShowSearch(true)}>Search</button>
        </>
        }
        </>
    )
}

export default Mycomp;
```

Comment: Because you conditionally render `Mem ` so when `showSearch ? ` is true the `Mem ` is unmounted, when `showSearch ? ` is false, it's re-created (not re-render) again.

Comment: oh finally someone tell me why , and i got it

Comment: I am glad it helps you.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that the ***entire*** body of a functional component ***is*** the "render" function, and react can call "render" nearly any number of times (*paused/aborted/restarted/etc...*) it needs to during the render phase in order to compute a diff to know what needs to be flushed to the DOM during the commit phase. [React lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) The console log in the body of the function isn't an accurate measure of when a functional component is *actually* rendered, use `useEffect` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the comment from Tony Nguyen, it is because i use conditional render for the memorised component, thus it will trigger unmount of the memorised component. Therefore nothing can be memorised.

the solution is using css to hide it instead of not render it for my case